# What is the most reliable way to log in to Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, openid, login

I am using my OpenID `sgsawant.myopenid.com` to log in to the Stack Exchange websites. But I wonder what will happen to my stack accounts if the website `myopenid.com` goes bust.

I really like the concept of Stack Exchange . In some way you build up currency by helping others. That currency can be used to get help on several topics. I am a grad student in engineering and I use the sites quite often. I wanted to know if there's a more reliable way to log in.

I somehow suspect that it boils down to the future probabilities. Like the probability of Google going bust (i.e. for using my Google account) compared with the probability of MyOpenID going bust (the logic can be extended by comparing the probabilities of other log in methods going bust).

Comment: The most reliable way to log in is to never log out

Comment: Currency? I can get *paid*? :o

Comment: Yes, MyOpenID is no longer a recommended provider, given the problems their service has recently experienced. Google, Facebook, or Stack Exchange's own OpenID provider are all good choices, and as Robotnik points out, the *best* solution is to have multiple options available and linked to your SE account.

Comment: @animuson It's called rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your page, along the right side of the line with your name is "*my logins*" which will allow you to add multiple logins to your stack exchange account (Google, Yahoo, Stack Exchange etc).

Adding multiple accounts doesn't remove the risk of losing your account, but it certainly alleviates it :)

Comment: Yup. I think I am probably safe with my Google and Facebook logins linked to my SE accounts!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But why do you say that adding multiple accounts doesn't remove the risk? It suddenly dawned on me that logging in with Stack Exchange account is perhaps the best way. That way the account is safe as long as the stackexchange websites are present (in the absence of which my original question is rendered moot of course).

Comment: Haha I only say that it doesn't remove the risk because there is the SLIGHTEST chance that say Google AND Yahoo go down. For arguments sake lets say that any given day the chance that Google goes bankrupt is 1%. Same with Yahoo, 1%. So the chance that both go down on the same day is 0.01*0.01 = 0.001 (or 1/1000). Unlikely, but still a chance. Of course as you mentioned adding a Stack Exchange account means you will have an account as long as Stack Exchange is up :)